# How to return everything from a cypher that has limit

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

Pretty much all my cyphers are parameterized with **limit {l}**. 
The caller is expected to pass the l as input. 
However, i have a new requirement to **NOT** limit results. e.g. if caller passes 2 as limit i return 2 rows, however if caller passes -1 / 0 as limit i should return everything?

I can obviously keep two queries, one with limit and other without limit and do if/else. Wondering if there is a smarter way to unlimit the cypher that has limit clause in it.

Comment: Seems that there is no way to have this in a Cypher query. Is your query string static or is it dynamically built? In the latter case you could append the limit clause only when the client passes a value different from -1.

Comment: For now i am dynamically generating the query based on whether i have to limit or not. I refuse to be content with that approach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported. However, you could raise an issue to allow expressions in SKIP and LIMIT?